# Spring data neo4j cypher query

Tags: cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have two relationships in my cypher query:  **CREATE_BY**    and     **LIKE**

I want to list down all blogs created by someone, people can **LIKE** blog, so i also want to know the likesCount too, below query has one problem is that when nobody **LIKE** this blog, then this blog won't be in the results. How to fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
@Query("START owner=node({0}) MATCH owner<-[:CREATE_BY]-blog WHERE blog.status = 0 
WITH blog MATCH blog<-[:LIKE]-user RETURN blog, count(*) AS likesCount ORDER BY 
blog.createDate DESC")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, try making the LIKE relationship optional, e.g blog<-[?:LIKE]-user. Here's doc [link for neo4j 1.9.5](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9.5/query-match.html#match-optional-typed-and-named-relationship)

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9.5/query-match.html#match-optional-typed-and-named-relationship